# Is there a way to have GitLab Cache be consumed without being written to?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci-runner, continuous-delivery

I have a gitlab job that downloads a bunch of dependencies and stuffs them in a cache (if necessary), then I have a bunch of jobs that use that cache. I notice at the end of the consuming jobs, they spend a bunch of time creating a new cache, even though they made no changes to it.

Is it possible to have them act only as consumers? Read-only?

```
cache:
  paths:
    - assets/
configure:
  stage: .pre
  script:
    - conda env update --prefix ./assets/env/base -f ./environment.yml; 
    - source activate ./assets/env/base 
    - bash ./download.sh
parse1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - source activate ./assets/env/base;
    - ./build.sh -b test -s 2
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build
parse2:
  stage: build
  script:
    - source activate ./assets/env/base;
    - ./build.sh -b test -s 2
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buried deeply in the **very** detailed [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html) documentation is a reference to a `cache` setting called [`policy`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cachepolicy). GitLab caches have the concept of `push` (aka `write`) and `pull` (aka `read`). By default it is set to `pull-push` (`read` at the beginning and `write` at the end).

> If you know the job does not alter the cached files, you can skip the upload step by setting `policy: pull` in the job specification. Typically, this would be twinned with an ordinary cache job at an earlier stage to ensure the cache is updated from time to time:
>
> [`.gitlab-ci.yml` > `cache:policy`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#cachepolicy)

Which pretty much describes this situation: the job `configure` updates the cache, and the `parse` jobs do not alter the cache.

In the consuming jobs, add:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - assets/
  policy: pull
```

For clarity, it probably wouldn't hurt to make that explicit in the global setting:

```
cache:
  paths:
    - assets/
  policy: pull-push
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR. Overwrite `cache` with no `path` element.

You probably have to add a key element to your global cache configuration too. I actually have never used without a key element.

See the cache documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#how-archiving-and-extracting-works)